# Regex Match one of strings

Tags: regex, f#

```
        let m = Regex.Match(X.Text, "\\b(select)|(where)|(from)\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

it highlights only Select , so I guess the trouble is in my Regex.Match syntax, but I can't see where ?

with alll the changes my current solution is looking like this :

```
module SQL_Highlighing

open System.Runtime.InteropServices

module Lock =
    [<DllImport(@"User32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = false, ExactSpelling = true)>]
    extern void LockWindowUpdate(int hWnd)

open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Drawing

type SyntaxRTB() = 
    inherit System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()

    override X.OnTextChanged(e : System.EventArgs) =
        base.OnTextChanged(e); X.ColorTheKeyWords()

    member X.ColorTheKeyWords() =
        let HL s c =
            let color(m : Match, color : Color) =
                X.SelectionStart    <- m.Index
                X.SelectionLength   <- m.Length
                X.SelectionColor    <- color
            Regex.Matches(X.Text, "\\b" + s + "\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) |> fun mx ->
                for m in mx do if (m.Success) then color(m,c)

        let SelectionAt = X.SelectionStart
        Lock.LockWindowUpdate(X.Handle.ToInt32())

        HL "(select)|(where)|(from)|(top)|(order)|(group)|(by)|(as)|(null)" Color.Blue
        HL "(join)|(left)|(inner)|(outer)|(right)|(on)" Color.Red
        HL "(and)|(or)|(not)" Color.DarkSlateGray
        HL "(case)|(when)|(then)|(else)|(end)" Color.BurlyWood
        HL "(cast)|(nvarchar)|(bit)" Color.BlueViolet
        HL "(datepart)" Color.Teal

        X.SelectionStart    <- SelectionAt
        X.SelectionLength   <- 0
        X.SelectionColor    <- Color.Black
    Lock.LockWindowUpdate(0)
```

Comment: I doubt it's related to your problem, but your P/Invoke signature is wrong. It should be `extern bool LockWindowUpdate(nativeint hWnd)` and `SetLastError` should be set to `false`.

Comment: Hhm, it will only highlight the first select, where or from. Use `Regex.Matches` instead. That may be the problem (haven't tested your code).

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish with the `\\b`s? Are you really expecting backspace literals in your input data?

Comment: @lasseespeholt add it to answers , let mx = Regex.Matches(X.Text, "\\b(select)|(where)|(from)\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        for m in mx do
            if (m.Success) then color(m,Color.Blue) solved my trouble.

Comment: @ildjarn When `\b` is outside a character class then it means "word boundary", see http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: upon a quick Google research f# regex I found an interesting [blog entry](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/05/10/f-regular-expressionsactive-patterns/)

Comment: @lasseespeholt : Ah, right, I forgot about zero-width assertions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*migrated from comment*

`Regex.Match` will only give you the first match. Instead, you should use `Regex.Matches`.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using a regular expression test bed. I find [GSkinner RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) very useful.

\b is representing a boundary, but | is separating your expression. What you actually get is:

```
\b(select)
or
(where)
or
(from)\b
```

I assume that you want the boundary for each, so adding another group would prevent the separation:

```
\b((select)|(from)|(where))\b
```

Comment: +1 That's another problem :) A simplification would be `\b(select|from|where)\b` because `|` have lowest precedence.